# Play framework call webservice with bad url

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to do calling a webservice and get PDF file

```
val testPdf: String = "http://ivan/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fDGG%2fInvoice&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF"
val request = WS.url(testPdf).withAuth("user", "password", AuthScheme.BASIC)
  request.get().map {
    response => {
      val pdf = response.getAHCResponse.getResponseBodyAsBytes
    }
  }
```

I normally get a pdf with other links, such as http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf, but my reference contains no good characters - "%2f", which Java convert to slash.
How can I escape this url?

I'm in the play version 2.1.1

Comment: can you try this url: `http://ivan/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/DGG/Invoice&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF`